# JSF Tomcat 7 PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, tomcat, el

I encounter a PropertyNotFoundException after upgrading from tomcat 6 to tomcat 7. This is the message I get:

```
value="#{someHandler.result.someList[1].doSomething(someDTO.id).value}": Property 'doSomething' not found on type com.someproject.SomeClass
```

Can anyone explain why? I'm using jsf 2 (myfaces implementation), and yes, doSomething is no property, but value is. It works fine with tomcat 6. I get this exception after pressing a button (which would make the page refresh after doing some database access). The form is rendered fine the first time it is invoked!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
doSomething(someDTO.id)
```

EL prior 2.2 does by default not support method invocations like that. So why it works on Tomcat 6 which uses EL 2.1 is beyond me. Probably it had a custom EL implementation in its `/lib` folder.

However, since Tomcat 7.0 support EL 2.2, it should definitely work fine out the box on Tomcat 7.0. The only prerequirement is that your `web.xml` is declared conform the Servlet 3.0 spec so that EL 2.2 features will be triggered.

Ensure that your `web.xml` complies Servlet 3.0 and not 2.5 or older:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- config here -->
</web-app>
```